# Why is my screen going black after a minute or less of no input activity?

Tags: 16.04, grub2, power-management, idle

Today I edited by GRUB parameters to add a parameter that supposedly solves a problem with locking up after standby on my CPU (Intel Pentium quad N3540), as seen at the end of this line in the GRUB config file:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"

What I am now seeing is the screen goes black after fairly short periods of no key/mouse activity (Edit: I timed it - it is always about 14.5 seconds after the last user input and then the screen powers down), and comes back on as soon as I touch a key or move the mouse. I have never seen that issue before.

(Before the change, I had also for a long time been having a problem where the computer completely freezes every hour or so of active use, apparently a very rare reaction in response to some mouse events. I haven't seen that yet after the GRUB change.)

Suspend When Inactive is set to 30 minutes.

Dim Screen To Save Power was checked on, but set to 10 minutes. I just turned it off to see if that helps. I've been running on battery but with charge over 80%.

Update: After having turned off the Dim Screen To Save Power option, it still is going back after less than a minute of not making input.

This is an Acer Aspire E11 (E3-112-P1GT).

(I did the same GRUB settings change on a similar laptop (Pentium N3540, but Toshiba), but that computer did not show the same problem.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found an answer that worked in the second answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459603/laptop-screen-goes-blank-after-33-seconds-of-inactivity).

This other question's asker found a way to fix a very similar condition in 12.04, but I'm running 16.04 and the System Settings UI has been changed to something different (looks much more limited now - hmm....), and I had already tried flipping the setting that looks like the new equivalent, as mentioned above. My output from `xset q` looks like:

```
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
```

and switching the "Dim Screen To Save Power" checkbox in the 16.04 UI had no effect on that.

However, using the solution in the second answer on that question did work:

```
xset s off && xset -dpms
```

Which apparently needs to be put in a user's profile to get it to happen each session at the right time.

This results in:

```
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
  DPMS is Disabled
```

(This seems to be a bug, to me. I'm not sure where to file it.)

Comment: I've added the command to `~/.bashrc` with  `echo 'xset s off && xset -dpms' >> ~/.bashrc` and works correctly.

Comment: Had this problem in Ubuntu 20. This fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of anyone searching for solutions to this apparently-common problem:

If other solutions (using control panel, using the 'xset' command with various options, etc.) do not solve this for you, you might try this:

```
sudo apt-get remove phoneui-apps phoneuid phonefsod
```

Explanation:

I tried numerous combinations of xset commands, and every GUI I could find that claimed to relate to screen blanking, but nothing worked - most of the time, the screen would blank after ~33 seconds of inactivity.

It occurred to me that perhaps some wayward daemon was doing this for some reason, so I looked at system logs, and found this in /var/log/auth.log:

```
Jan  3 15:48:01 my-host-name dbus[886]: [system] Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.8" (uid=0 pid=1115 comm="/usr/sbin/phonefsod ") interface="org.freesmartphone.Device.Display" member="SetBrightness" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freesmartphone.odeviced" (uid=0 pid=959 comm="/usr/sbin/fsodeviced ")
Jan  3 15:48:14 my-host-name dbus[886]: message repeated 2 times: [ [system] Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.8" (uid=0 pid=1115 comm="/usr/sbin/phonefsod ") interface="org.freesmartphone.Device.Display" member="SetBrightness" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freesmartphone.odeviced" (uid=0 pid=959 comm="/usr/sbin/fsodeviced ")]
Jan  3 15:48:23 my-host-name dbus[886]: [system] Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.8" (uid=0 pid=1115 comm="/usr/sbin/phonefsod ") interface="org.freesmartphone.Device.Display" member="SetBrightness" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freesmartphone.odeviced" (uid=0 pid=959 comm="/usr/sbin/fsodeviced ")
Jan  3 15:48:31 my-host-name dbus[886]: message repeated 2 times: [ [system] Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.8" (uid=0 pid=1115 comm="/usr/sbin/phonefsod ") interface="org.freesmartphone.Device.Display" member="SetBrightness" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freesmartphone.odeviced" (uid=0 pid=959 comm="/usr/sbin/fsodeviced ")]
Jan  3 15:48:41 my-host-name dbus[886]: [system] Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.8" (uid=0 pid=1115 comm="/usr/sbin/phonefsod ") interface="org.freesmartphone.Device.Display" member="SetBrightness" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freesmartphone.odeviced" (uid=0 pid=959 comm="/usr/sbin/fsodeviced ")
Jan  3 15:49:01 my-host-name dbus[886]: [system] Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.8" (uid=0 pid=1115 comm="/usr/sbin/phonefsod ") interface="org.freesmartphone.Device.Display" member="SetBrightness" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freesmartphone.odeviced" (uid=0 pid=959 comm="/usr/sbin/fsodeviced ")
```

The references to "Device.Display" and "SetBrightness" seemed suspiciously relevant.  I don't specifically recall installing these packages, but I was trying to extract data from a semi-functional mobile phone a while back, so I probably did it then.  In any case, I knew I didn't need these packages now, so I removed them (see 'apt-get remove' command, above), sat back, and waited for the screen to blank... and waited some more... and it didn't.  :-D

Again, I suggest trying the other possible solutions (system settings GUI, xset commands, etc.) first, simply because they apparently solve the problem for some people, and they seem more likely to work.  OTOH, unless you happen to be using these packages, removing them is harmless (and if they're not installed, apt-get will just say so and you haven't hurt anything).  Hopefully, this will help someone...

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem stopped after enrolling an MOK key for safe boot (which apparently was required to use an onboard laptop GPU; conceivably I could have just turned off safe boot) and taking out a `nouveau.modeset=0` line in my /etc/defaults/grub file (also set to prevent GPU problems).  Possibly the fix was one or the other and not both.

Another factor that appears to be involved is use of lightdm instead of gdm3, the latter apparently having some sort of conflict with an unresolved nvidia bug. And finally in /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config you may want to set `needs_root_rights=yes`.